# How to slice a list with START being larger than STOP

Tags: python

I want to slice a list from START to STOP, but have the iteration continue past the last element, and circle all the way back to the first element. Then continue stepping till reaching STOP.

I tried list slicing like so:

```
    list_a = list(range(8))
    reordered_list = list_a[5:2]
```

But only received an empty list:

```
    []
```

Ideally i want **list_a** to print out:

```
    [5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
```

Basically, I want the traversal to go "full circle" and continue the iteration at index 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
def foo(list_a, start, stop):
    if (start <= stop):
        return list_a[start:stop]
    else:
        return list_a[start:] + list_a[:stop]
```

Output:

```
>>> x = list(range(8))
>>> foo(x, 5, 2)
[5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks DrNightmare! I like your succinct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def parse(input, start, stop):
    partial_list = input[:stop]
    return partial_list[start:] + partial_list[:start]

full_list = range(8)
parse(full_list, 2, 5)  # Outputs [2, 3, 4, 0, 1]
```

EDIT: there is some inconsistency in your question, if possible please reword.

Answer (score 2):

When you give a slice index like -

```
list_a[5:2]
```

It would take a step of 1, and since the start is after the stop, there is no elements between those indices (slicing would not cycle on its own) .

You should use `modulus` (remainder) operator and a for loop or list comprehension to get the list you want. Example -

```
def foo(list_a, start, stop):
    if start >= len(list_a):
        start = len(list_a) - 1
    if stop >= len(list_a):
        stop = len(list_a) - 1
    i = start
    ret = []
    while i != stop:
        ret.append(list_a[i])
        i = (i+1)%len(list_a)
    return ret
```

---

Example/Demo -

```
>>> def foo(list_a, start, stop):
...     if start >= len(list_a):
...         start = len(list_a) - 1
...     if stop >= len(list_a):
...         stop = len(list_a) - 1
...     i = start
...     ret = []
...     while i != stop:
...         ret.append(list_a[i])
...         i = (i+1)%len(list_a)
...     return ret
...
>>> foo(list(range(8)),5,2)
[5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator, `%`:

```
>>> l = list(range(8))
>>> start = 5
>>> while start%len(l) != 2:
...     print(l[start%len(l)])
...     start += 1
...
5
6
7
0
1
```

As a function:

```
>>> def foo(l, start, end):
...     result = []
...     while start%len(l) != end:
...         result.append(l[start%len(l)])
...         start += 1
...     return result
...
>>> foo(l, 5, 2)
[5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The modulus operator is your friend here. Whenever you request an index of the list, request [index] mod [size of list].

```
MyList[i%len(Mylist)]
```

In your case, write a check where if the end index is less than the start index, add the size of the list to the end index and then use the code I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
>>> reordered = (list_a[5:]+list_a[:2])
>>> print (reordered)
>>> [5, 6, 7, 0, 1]
```

Basically slicing and then adding them together.